# prolog - extract terms from a list

Tags: list, prolog

Well I have some elementary parts of cars, eg:

```
elementary_part( spoke ).
elementary_part( rim ).
elementary_part( hub ).
```

and some subcomponents, eg:

```
subcomponent( wheel, [quant( spoke, 5 ), quant( rim, 1 ), quant( hub, 1)] ).
```

and I'm trying to write a "consists_of" program that gives the elementary parts, eg

```
consists_of(wheel, P).
```

I have so far make it through this point:

```
consists_of(wheel, P):- parts(wheel, P).
quant(X,Y):- write(Y), write(' piece(s) of '), write(X), write('.'), nl.
parts(X,Y):- subcomponent(X, [H|T]), print_a_list([H|T]).

print_a_list([]).
print_a_list([H | T]) :- nl, write(H), print_a_list(T).
```

What I get as a result is:

```
?- consists_of(wheel,P).

quant(spoke,5)
quant(rim,1)
quant(hub,1)
true.
```

...which is not what I want. I get the correct result when I try

```
consists_of(wheel, P):- quant( spoke, 5 ), quant( rim, 1 ), quant( hub, 1).
```

but since I'm doing this for many car-parts I know this isn't the solution.

Am I missing sth? How can I exctract separately the elements of the list so that 'quant(X,Y)' will be shown correctly? Or at least that only the elements are shown,and not the compound term with the functor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to replace the call to `write(H)` by the call to `quant`:

```
print_a_list([]).
print_a_list([quant(X,Y) | T]) :- nl, quant(X,Y), print_a_list(T).
```

If you still would like to keep your `print_a_list` as generic as possible do

```
print_a_list([]).
print_a_list([H | T]) :- nl, write_q(H), print_a_list(T).
```

and

```
write_q(H) :- H.
```

Some people might dislike the last solution so an alternative would be

```
write_q(quant(X,Y)):- write(Y), write(' piece(s) of '), write(X), write('.'), nl.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the last two solutions work, the first one had some errors but I'm satisfied, couldn't put my finger on it and it seemed rather simple in the end, thank you!